# TDA7297 muting via microcontroller

Tags: arduino, amplifier

I've followed the low-cost circuit design for the TDA7297 found on the [electro-dan](https://electro-dan.co.uk/Electronics/TDA7297_TDA7266.aspx) website to make a simple amp.

*Low cost schematic:*
[image: Low cost schematic]

I now want to control the muting using an arduino.

[image]

I'm not overly interested in setting the amp into standby, just muting/unmuting.

The datasheet mentions a mute threshold of 2.3v - 4.1v, yet the low-cost schematic is tying both the mute & standby together, when using a 12v supply I estimate this to be around 6v, which is above the maximum threshold specified.

Will I be ok just using the arduino 5v pin output to trigger the mute feature (with the 10k resistor and 1uF capacitor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet has a picture of the mute and stand-by driven directly from a MCU.

So if you have a MCU with 5V as GPIO voltage, you can directly use the diagram you have and connect the 10k resistors to MCU IO pins.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, 
The datasheet doesn't mention the typical GPIO voltage, as some are 3.3v and 5v, so I  was wondering if I need to reduce the voltage from the arduino pin to get it within the mute threshold, e.g. below 4.1v?

I'm assuming that the capacitor on the mute pin should be tied to the arduino ground and not the ground used on the amp (12v)?

Comment: @Dave You are thinking it incorrectly. The MCU must use 5V supply for 5V IO voltage to go above the 4.1V threshold. A 3.3V MCU with 3.3V IO voltages can't control the mute pin as it will always be below 4.1V mute threshold. And the Arduino and amplifier chip **must** share the same ground in order to even work, so yes the cap connects to both amp and Arduino ground.

Comment: @Justme, upvoted and it's always a pleasure to see you here but...do you *ever* sleep? :-D You've done early AM through to late PM today and I'd say that's a normal shift for you :-) (I'm stuck on a PC working today so I'm dipping in and out here for the change of scenery...)

Comment: @Justme Many thanks for your help with this. Much appreciated 